# MySQL-Statement. How do i skip rows in query where all rows equal null

Tags: mysql, sql, select, pivot, where-clause

I have created a query to construct a table with the following code:

```
SELECT Date, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN UniqueId = 'NonComLong' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS 'NonComLong',
    SUM(CASE WHEN UniqueId = 'NonComShort' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS 'NonComShort',
        SUM(CASE WHEN UniqueId = 'NonComNetLong' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS 'NonComNetLong',
        SUM(CASE WHEN UniqueId = 'NonComPos' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS 'NonComPos',
        SUM(CASE WHEN UniqueId = 'TotalPositions' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS 'TotalPositions',
        SUM(CASE WHEN UniqueId = 'NonComPosShare' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS 'NonComPosShare'
FROM fundamental_data WHERE AttributeId = 160 AND Date >= '2011-06-14'
GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY Date;
```

The above code returns the following table:

[Image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9mCS.png)

I would like to write a piece of in which i can skip a row if all columns except the date column returns NULL. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so you want to query rows with complete data?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: As i have described above, i am asking for help in trying to skip the rows where MySQL returns null. So yes, i want to query rows with complete data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that column `value` is not `null`able, you can add another condition to the `WHERE` clause that ensures that at least one of the conditions in the aggregate functions will be met:

```
SELECT ...
FROM fundamental_data 
WHERE 
    AttributeId = 160 
    AND Date >= '2011-06-14'
    AND UniqueId IN (
        'NonComLong',
        'NonComShort',
        'NonComNetLong',
        'NonComPos',
        'TotalPositions',
        'NonComPosShare'
    )
```

If `value` may be `null`, you would just add another condition:

```
WHERE
    ...
    AND value IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: But how would you create seperate columns for the seperate UniqueId's with that method?

Comment: @Spedtsberg: yo ucan keep your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses just as they are right now. I just suggested changes to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Wow, that did the trick. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out.